# How to iterate through a S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I am trying to train a neural network where I pass in a series of images. I want to create a generator which passes each image in as a numpy array

```
from skimage import io
image_array = io.imread(url)
```

But this is only for a specific amazon aws url. I know the standard way using the boto library is something like this:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'hello.txt', '/tmp/hello.txt')
```

But again here, it seems like you are pointing towards a specific resource

I want something like this:

```
def my_generator():
    for object in s3_bucket():     # does an s3_bucket() iterator like this exist?
        image_array = io.imread(object)
        yield image_array
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like:

```
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    print(key.key)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and skip the first 100 files in the bucket?